# Tabularx: Reason why customized \hrule exceeds \textwidth?

Tags: tables, tabularx, rules, textwidth, hline

Any ideas on why my self configured `\hrule` exceeds the specified `\textwidth` of my page layout?

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\thickline}{%
        \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \color{red}\hrule height 5pt
        \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ll}
    test & test \\\thickline
    test & test \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: because your table not star at left text border but it is indented. put `\noindent` before it or put your table in `table` environment.

Comment: @Zarko: Please post this as an answer - awesome! :-) Thank you very much!

Comment: Unrelated: load `xcolor` with option `[table]`: it will load `colortbl` and add further commands, such as`\rowcolors`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`article`, if you do not define otherwise, starts paragraphs with some indentation (exceptions are paragraphs immediately after sections' titles). It can be removed by:

- adding `\noindent` immediately before the `tabularx` environment
- enclosing the `tabularx` environment in float environment `table`
- enclosing it in a `center` environmemt

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[table]{xcolor} % loads 'colortbl' automatically
  \usepackage{tabularx}

  \makeatletter
      \newcommand{\thickline}{%
          \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \color{red}\hrule height 5pt
          \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
      }
  \makeatother

  %---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
  \usepackage{showframe}
  \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
  \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%

  \begin{document}
  \section{Tests}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
      test & test \\\thickline
      test & test \\
  \end{tabularx}

  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
      test & test \\\thickline
      test & test \\
  \end{tabularx}

  \bigskip
  or

  \begin{table}[htb]
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
      test & test \\\thickline
      test & test \\
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}

  or

  \begin{center}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
      test & test \\\thickline
      test & test \\
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{center}

  \end{document}
  ```

[image]